# Alterar "Step" no "printing progress" do Quickreport

Tags: delphi, quickreport

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para impressão de cartelas, por isso envio arquivos extensos para impressão, algo em torno de 25000 paginas por vês. Devido a essa grande quantidade páginas o "printing progress" do `Quickreport` demora 2 minutos para avançar os 5% de passo. Como faço para alterar o passo/avanço (também chamado de stepIt no progressBar) no Quickreport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não encontrei uma forma "convencional", mas é possível alterar o avanço diretamente no arquivo do próprio Quickreport.
A unit se chama "qrprgres.pas" e fica na pasta raiz de instalação do Quickreport. Basta ir até o método `procedure TQRProgressForm.CMQRPROGRESSUPDATE(var Message);` e alterar a linha `if (FQRPrinter.Progress mod 5) = 0 then` para `if (FQRPrinter.Progress mod 2) = 0 then` e recompilar, assim o avanço passará a ser de 2%.